# Magento 2, When qoute calculate subtotal?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, api, addtocart

Using `magento 2.2`, `API`. I created a web service for *add multi-product* in to cart, but not calculate **subtotal**. *Help please!*

**CODE**

```
/**
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function addMultiItemToCart($email, $storeId, $items)
{
    try {
        // Init store information
        $store = $this->storeFactory->create()->load($storeId);
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

        // init cutomer information
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($email); // load customet by email address

        // Create Quote
        $quote = $this->quote->create(); // Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); // set store for which you create quote

        // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->setSubtotal(0);
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); // Assign quote to customer

        // Add items in quote
        $validItem = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item->getId());
            $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
        }

        $quote->save();
        $items = $quote->getAllItems();
        return $items;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return [
            "MESSAGE" => "Add multi item to cart",
            "ERROR" => $e
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Help to correct my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate subtotal like below code:

```
// Add items in quote
$validItem = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item->getId());
    $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
    $quoteItemQty = $item['qty'];
    $quoteItemUnitPrice = $item['price'];
    $subTotal += ($quoteItemQty * $quoteItemUnitPrice);
}
$quote->setSubtotal($subTotal);
$quote->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal);
$quote->save();
```

Comment: When i use `{{url}}/V1/carts/mine/items` will return price always 0.

Comment: Need I to add any code?

Comment: can't you get product item price?

Comment: respond JSON from `{{url}}/V1/carts/mine/items`
>[
    {
        "item_id": 1869,
        "sku": "Simple Food",
        "qty": 2,
        "name": "Simple Food",
        "price": 0,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "1013"
    }
]

Comment: ` "price": 0`  i got price alway 0.

Comment: can you please check wheather  "$item->getPrice()" return item price?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is, after you save your items to cart, you have calculate their subtotal, only if when the subtotal is not affected as per the quantity and number of items. To do this you have to use pricehelper(it is preferable to use pricehelper with your construct function and not with objectmanager), and after that save total for all the items added into the cart. Hope it might helps.

```
1.
    $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

//this is how you can calculate subtotal for all the items in cart
$priceHelper->currency($item->getPrice()*$item->getQty(), true, false);

2.
//use this after you save your items
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```

First try with 2 only, if not working then use 1.

Comment: How to set price for `quote`?

Comment: you don't have to set price, while adding product to cart, as this will be automatically as soon as you add a product. Also, it's not a good practice/error prone if you try to set price manually, if in case it doesn't change the price of cart, all you need to do is to

$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();

use this, However if you still wants to set price you can use this 

$base_subtotal = $priceHelper->currency($item->getPrice()*$item->getQty(), true, false);